# ActiveAdmin Sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

How do you get ActiveAdmin **index** page to sort a certain column on default beside using **default_scope** for the resource index page? I tried many things and none works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from [active admin index page documentation](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html):

**Index default sort order**
*You can define the default sort order for index pages:*

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  config.sort_order = "name_asc"
end
```